# IOS:how to get value from dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

In my project I am showing the values of `NSMutableDictionary` on a `UITableview`.  It works fine. On my `UITableView` I also have an Edit `button`. The only thing I want is that when I click on edit `button` the whole data will show on the next view.
The values which have to shown on edit view will get on the basis of Key- 'id'.
Please help me to how to get the value of Key- 'id'. and use it on the second view to display details.

I am using the following code:

```
-(void)physiciandata

    {

        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data[Users][ref_id]=%@&api_key=bf45c093e542f057c123ae7d6",refidstr];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.20/hsch/api/user_procedure_list"]];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"str : %@",str);



        NSDictionary *dict6 = [self cleanJsonToObject:responseData];
        //NSLog(@"str : %@",dict6);


        physiciandict = [[[dict6 objectForKey:@"procedure"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"PhysiciansProcedures"];
        physiciandict1 = [[[dict6 objectForKey:@"procedure"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Procedures"];

        //diagnosedictforname = [[[dict6 objectForKey:@"diagnoses"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Diagnoses"];


        NSLog(@" for ref id =%@ ,   data is= %@ , and %@ " ,refidstr, physiciandict , physiciandict1);


        CompletephyDic = [physiciandict mutableCopy];

        [CompletephyDic addEntriesFromDictionary:physiciandict1];

        NSLog(@"Complete data is %@",CompletephyDic);
    }
```

and this is the code I put to display data on tableView

```
{

            NSString *strid = [physiciandict objectForKey:@"id"];
            serialnmbrphysician.text = @"";
            serialnmbrphysician.text = strid;
            serialnmbrphysician.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            NSLog(@"data1 %@",strid);

            NSString * strName= [CompletephyDic objectForKey:@"procedure_name"];
            procedurename.text = @"";
            procedurename.text = strName;
            procedurename.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            NSLog(@"data2 %@",strName);

            NSString *strName2 = [CompletephyDic objectForKey:@"procedure_code"];
            procedurecode.text = @"";
            procedurecode.text = strName2;
            procedurecode.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            NSLog(@"data3 %@",strName2);


            NSString *strName3 = [physiciandict objectForKey:@"charge_amt"];
            averagemedicareallowedamount.text = @"";
            averagemedicareallowedamount.text = strName3;
            averagemedicareallowedamount.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            NSLog(@"data4 %@",strName3);


            NSString *strName4 = [physiciandict objectForKey:@"total_amt"];
            avgsubmittedchargeamount.text = @"";
            avgsubmittedchargeamount.text = strName4;
            avgsubmittedchargeamount.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            NSLog(@"data5 %@",strName4);

            NSString *strName5 = [physiciandict objectForKey:@"medicare_amt"];
            avgmedicarepaymentamount.text = @"";
            avgmedicarepaymentamount.text = strName5;
            avgmedicarepaymentamount.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            NSLog(@"data6 %@",strName5);
}
```

Comment: Create model named procedure, and populate with your dictionary data. Then you can populate an array with these procedure models.Then it will be easy to access your data for showing in next screen.

Comment: Provide the code what you have done in tableview data source and delegate method